# How to handle multiple feed permission in GetStream

Tags: getstream-io

I need to specify multiple permission for a single user, for example having full access to a specific feed but also have read access to an other one. but getstream only allows one specific permission per token.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are not configurable yet via APIs or Dashboard but if you reach out to Stream support email we can set that up for you.